# Volume on a model using a black and white texture

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes, bump

I have a brush model that came with all it’s textures here and I was wondering how I could apply the black and white “ink” texture and make it have some volume on it, possibly without using bump node since when I tried it really didn't work.

The first image is the texture that came with the model

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you, I’ll fix this question whenever I can today and I apologize for any issues, English is not my first language so I’m still trying to learn how to formulate questions appropriately